# ultimos 2 meses Diferentes

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

tengo una lista de registro por cada SKU; entonces por cada SKU desearia poder obtener los precios de los ultimos 2 meses **Diferentes**(Meses registrados) (y que pueda reconocer entre cambios anuales como diciembre 2016 y enero 2017) el problema que hay salto entre meses.

la tabla tiene el siguiente esquema

```
id  sku     precio  fecha Actualizacion
1   10101   7.40    2016-12-23 11:58:05
2   10102   7.35    2016-12-23 11:58:06
3   10103   7.70    2016-12-23 11:58:07
4   10101   7.40    2017-02-15 11:58:05
5   10102   7.35    2017-02-15 11:58:06
6   10103   7.70    2017-02-15 11:58:07
7   10101   7.50    2017-05-06 11:58:11
8   10102   7.55    2017-05-06 11:58:12
9   10103   7.90    2017-05-06 11:58:05
```

estaba tratando de adaptar este ejemplo:

```
SELECT id, thread_id, user_id, subject, body, date_sent
  FROM messages WHERE date_sent IN (
    SELECT MAX( date_sent )
      FROM messages WHERE user_id =6 GROUP BY thread_id
  )
ORDER BY thread_id ASC , date_sent DESC;
```

**Actualización:**

Manipulando me queda algo asi, pero me toca prevenir que tome 2 registros del mismo mes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabla
WHERE 
    (YEAR(`Date_Rel`) <= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    AND 
    (MONTH(`Date_Rel`) <= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    ORDER 
    BY `Date_Rel` DESC;
```

Comment: podes agregar el ejemplo de la salida que esperas con esos datos? y si podes, armas un fiddle para que te podamos ayudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no te entendí mal, lo que buscas es obtener un precio por mes de los últimos dos meses de cada sku. Es decir que deberías tener como máximo dos registros por sku. Te doy un ejemplo de como podrías resolverlo:

#### En primer lugar creamos una tabla con tu ejemplo

```
create table Ejemplo (
    id      int,
    sku     varchar(15),
    precio  numeric(15,2),
    fecha   datetime
);  

insert into Ejemplo(id, sku, precio, fecha)
  values (1,'10101',7.40,'2016-12-23 11:58:05'),
         (2,'10102',7.35,'2016-12-23 11:58:06'),
         (3,'10103',7.70,'2016-12-23 11:58:07'),
         (4,'10101',7.40,'2017-02-15 11:58:05'),
         (5,'10102',7.35,'2017-02-15 11:58:06'),
         (6,'10103',7.70,'2017-02-15 11:58:07'),
         (7,'10101',7.50,'2017-05-06 11:58:11'),
         (8,'10102',7.55,'2017-05-06 11:58:12'),
         (9,'10103',7.90,'2017-05-06 11:58:05');
```

#### Luego la consulta en sí:

```
Select   e.*
         from Ejemplo e
         INNER JOIN (select e1.sku,
                            @rownum := IF(e1.sku=@sku, @rownum+1, 1) AS RowNumber,
                            @sku := e1.sku,
                            e1.fecha
                            FROM ( select t.sku, 
                                           year(t.fecha) * 100 + month(t.fecha) as Periodo,
                                           max(t.fecha) as fecha
                                           from Ejemplo t
                                           group by t.sku, year(t.fecha) * 100 + month(t.fecha)
                                           order by t.sku, year(t.fecha) * 100 + month(t.fecha) desc
                                  ) e1
                                  cross join (SELECT @sku:=(SELECT MIN(sku) FROM Ejemplo), @rownum:=0) AS init 
                     ) rn
                     on rn.sku = e.sku
                     and rn.fecha = e.fecha
                     and rn.RowNumber <= 2
          order by e.sku,
                   e.fecha desc;
```

#### Explicación

- En primer lugar, hacemos una consulta agrupada por sku y período (año/mes) y con la última fecha (`MAX`) de cada uno de estos grupos
- Luego numeramos cada uno de estos registros por grupo
- Y por último recuperamos todos los sku cuya fecha coincida al menos con los últimos dos registros de cada período.

#### Si por el contrario quieres una sola fila por `sku`

```
Select   e.sku,
         max(case when rn.RowNumber = 1 then e.fecha else null end)  as 'fecha1',
         max(case when rn.RowNumber = 1 then e.precio else null end) as 'precio1',
         max(case when rn.RowNumber = 2 then e.fecha else null end)  as 'fecha2',
         max(case when rn.RowNumber = 2 then e.precio else null end) as 'precio2'
         from Ejemplo e
         INNER JOIN (select e1.sku,
                            @rownum := IF(e1.sku=@sku, @rownum+1, 1) AS RowNumber,
                            @sku := e1.sku,
                            e1.fecha
                            FROM ( select t.sku, 
                                           year(t.fecha) * 1000 + month(t.fecha) as Periodo,
                                           max(t.fecha) as fecha
                                           from Ejemplo t
                                           group by t.sku, year(t.fecha) * 1000 + month(t.fecha)
                                           order by t.sku, year(t.fecha) * 1000 + month(t.fecha) desc
                                  ) e1
                                  cross join (SELECT @sku:=(SELECT MIN(sku) FROM Ejemplo), @rownum:=0) AS init 
                     ) rn
                     on rn.sku = e.sku
                     and rn.fecha = e.fecha
                     and rn.RowNumber <= 2
          group by e.sku           
          order by e.sku;
```

Answer (score 0):

No tengo claro el nombre de la tabla ni los campos pero esta consulta te debería devolver lo que solicitas.

SELECT sku, precio 
FROM tabla 
WHERE fecha_actualizacion BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND now()

Esto te devolverá todos los precios que se hayan registrado desde hace dos meses a partir de ahora.

Comment: esto funciona tomando como partida la fecha de hoy, el detalle es que deben ser los ultimos 2 registro de los ultimos 2 meses Registrado y como vez en el ejemplo de la tabla si tomas como fecha de partida hoy no encontraras nada.